# Sorting python list of lists with custom comparator

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, comparator

I'm trying to sort the below list of list:

`points = [[1, 4, 'start'], [1, 6, 'start'], [2, 8, 'end'], [2, 5, 'end'], [3, 4, 'end'], [3, 9, 'start']]`

Expected output:

`[[1, 6, 'start'], [1, 4, 'start'], [2, 5, 'end'], [2, 8, 'end'], [3, 9, 'start'], [3, 4, 'end']]`

Conditions for sorting are:

1. If p1[0] == p2[0] and p1[2] == 'start' and p2[2] == 'start', then p1[1] or p2[1] with greater value should come first.
2. If p1[0] == p2[0] and p1[2] == 'end' and p2[2] == 'end', then p1[1] or p2[1] with lesser value should come first.
3. If p1[0] == p2[0] and p1[2] == 'start' and p2[2] == 'end', then point with 'start' should come first.

I tried to write a custom comparator (getting correct answer), just wondering is this the right approach? Can it be more simpler?

```
def mycmp(p1, p2):
    if p1[0] < p2[0]:
        return -1

    if p1[0] == p2[0]:
        if p1[2] == 'start' and p2[2] == 'start' and p1[1] > p2[1]:
            return -1
        elif p1[2] == 'end' and p2[2] == 'end' and p1[1] < p2[1]:
            return -1
        elif p1[2] == 'start' and p2[2] == 'end':
            return -1
    return 0

points.sort(key=cmp_to_key(mycmp))
```

Comment: This function would never return `1`? That doesn't seem quite right for a sort callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
points.sort(key = lambda x: (x[0], x[2] == 'end', -x[1] if x[2] == 'start' else x[1]))
```

Can you use `lambda`, the key is to specify the priorities in order, thanks to @Jack.

Used totally 3 keys inside the lambda function.

You first sort on `x[0] in ascending order`,

In case there is a tie there, you give `high priority to x[2] = end`

And finally you sort `x[1] in descending order if x[2]=start and ascending if x[2]=end`

`Logic is to specify your priorities in order inside the lambda function`

Comment: start should come before end; that doesn't seem to be considered here?

Comment: What is the priority order, is it 0>1>2, the numbers denoting the indices.

Comment: also, for `[2] == 'start'`, then `[1]` is descending, otherwise it's ascending.

Comment: Probably this will fix it: `(x[0], x[2] == 'end', -x[1] if x[2] == 'start' else x[1])`

Comment: `points.sort(key = lambda x: (x[0], x[2] == 'end', -x[1] if x[2] == 'start' else x[1]))` Yes this seems to work, I'll update my answer, thanks.

Comment: @SurajSubramanian: It works, could you please explain the lambda function here?

Comment: I have updated my answer, do comment if you find my explanation not clear.